# QFileDialog - Saving a file with specified file name

Tags: c++, qt

How can I let the user save a file using QFileDialog without allowing the user to change the file name?

I have been using this code:

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save File"),"commands.txt", tr("TXT files (*.txt)"));
```

However, it allows the user to change the file name. I want it so that the user can't change the file name and can only save the file under "commands.txt".

Comment: Since you essentially want a folder picker dialog, use the `Directory` [QFileDialog::FileMode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#FileMode-enum).

Comment: You'll have to make a custom dialog to do that. But I'd suggest *not* presenting the dialog. what are you trying to allow them to do with the dialog if you won;t let them change the name.

Comment: If name is not changeable, why not just use a message box, asking user if they want to save to the file, if they click YES, then save the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to choose the folder to save commands.txt use `QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory` and save the file into the specified folder. Don't forget to check returned string `isEmpty()`, this means that user clicked "cancel".

If you want to let user decide to save commands.txt or not use `QMessageBox` with Yes and No buttons.