# QFileDialog: force file name

Tags: c++, qt

I want to create a `QFileDialog` set to `QFileDialog::AnyFile` in which the file name is fixed (but the location can be changed).

So far I found the question [QFileDialog - Saving a file with specified file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38358583/qfiledialog-saving-a-file-with-specified-file-name), which was not answered.
There is the pseudo-answer of choosing the directory directly instead, which is what I did so far in my project. However, by people testing the program, this was found to be confusing, thus is not an acceptable answer.

What I tried so far is to derive `QFileDialog` and then enforce this, but I don't know what to try anymore. I managed to reset the file name when a different file is clicked by reacting to the appropriate signal:

```
FixedFileDialog::FixedFileDialog(QWidget* parent) : QFileDialog(parent)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(currentUrlChanged(const QString&)), this, SLOT(current_changed(const QString&)));
}

void FixedFileDialog::current_changed(const QString&)
{
    selectFile(_filename);
}
```

(With `_filename` being a member set at the beginning.)

This works so far, but it does not prevent the user from entering a different name in the line edit. And I haven't found any signal which is emitted in this case.

Another attempt was trying to access the `QLineEdit` widget itself to disable it, but I don't know how. I tried

```
QLineEdit* line_edit = dialog.d_func()->lineEdit();
```

(With `dialog` being of the derived class.)

This does not work, as `d_func()` is private in `QFileDialog`.

Does somebody have any other idea what to do?

Comment: [`QFileDialog::Directory`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#FileMode-enum) - is what you are looking for. You can select directory when you don't need file name modification.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I wrote specifically that I can't use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must admit that this what I got in mind is a dirty hack. On the other hand, the OP appeared somehow desperate to me. So, I post it (with some doubts in mind).

My idea raised due to the statement of OP:

> `QLineEdit* line_edit = dialog.d_func()->lineEdit();`
>
> (With dialog being of the derived class.)
>
> This does not work, as `d_func()` is private in `QFileDialog`.

While `d_func()` is private, Qt widgets provide a kind of back-door due to their owner-ship management which can be exploited:

Each `QObject` provides a list of its children. So, a simple traversal of this children tree should pass the `QLineEdit` in quest (which is the only one in the current implementation of `QFileDialog` I have in Qt 5.13).

This is what I tried in a sample:

```
/ Qt header:
#include <QtWidgets>

QLineEdit* findFirstQLineEdit(QWidget *pQWidget)
{
  //qDebug() << "Inspect" << pQWidget;
  const QObjectList pQObjs = pQWidget->children();
  for (QObject *pQObj : pQObjs) {
    if (QLineEdit *pQLineEdit = dynamic_cast<QLineEdit*>(pQObj)) {
      qDebug() << "Found:" << pQLineEdit;
      return pQLineEdit;
    } else if (QWidget *pQWidget = dynamic_cast<QWidget*>(pQObj)) {
      if (QLineEdit *pQLineEdit = findFirstQLineEdit(pQWidget)) {
        return pQLineEdit;
      }
    }
  }
  return nullptr;
}

// main application
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QFileDialog qFileDlg(nullptr,
    QString::fromUtf8("Choose Dir. to Save File"),
    QDir::currentPath());
  qFileDlg.show();
  // manipulate the file name input
  qFileDlg.selectFile("CMakeLists.txt");
  QLineEdit *const pQEdit = findFirstQLineEdit(&qFileDlg);
  pQEdit->setReadOnly(true);
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

[image: snapshot of testQFileDialogQLineEditReadOnly]

The file name line editor is read-only. Neither editing nor deleting is allowed but the contents may still be copied and changed from outside. (For this case, OP seems to have found another solution, already.)

**Note:**

My first idea was to call `findFirstQLineEdit()` in the constructor of a class derived from `QFileDialog`. This didn't work! The debug output proofed that the `QFileDialog` hasn't any children after construction. I came to the conclusion that the children of the `QFileDialog` are created at a later time – but surely have to be already created after `show()`.

To embed this hack into a derived class, it might be sufficient to do the manipulation in an override of `QFileDialog::showEvent()`. (I didn't test it.)

Comment: Ah thank you very much, works just fine. As for your note, I assume that it can be used immediately after construction. In my code, I create an object of the derived class, set some properties (like `setFileMode`) and then disable the widget using your code, before calling `exec()` on it.