# QStackWidget - Search by name

Tags: c++, qt5, qt-designer, stacklayout

I've searched a method into [QT5 Docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) and I couldn't find anything regarding a function that can get me all the elements within the StackWidget.

I have a StackWidget which contains the pages for my application, but so far the only way I found in order to be able to change that the page is this function `setCurrentIndex` which needs to take an index of that specific page. Is the anyway a function or something which cand return the name of the elements from that `stackWidget` or a way in which I can use the name of that object in order to change the page, not the index.

Comment: You can iterate over all children of the stack widget to find a specific. The resp. functions are inherited from the very super class `QObject`. (FYI: [SO: QFileDialog: force file name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62695494/7478597))

Answer (score 0):

You may name your stack widgets using [`QObject::setObjectName` function](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop), and then iterate over them to find desired widget using its name, which is [`QObject::objectName`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop).